Interpreting the correlation of fixed effects in a LMM
I calculated a Linear Mixed Model with the dependent variable "interest" that was measured on a scale from 1-7 and three fixed effects threatlevel, extremity and superhumanity that are all factors with 2 levels (0 and 1) and their interactions. This is my output in R:
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: interest ~ threatlevel * extremity * superhumanity + 
    (1 | ID) +      (1 | items_recode)
   Data: subset_data.long

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  3691.9   3746.3  -1835.0   3669.9     1029 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9717 -0.6725  0.0326  0.6630  2.8920 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID           (Intercept) 1.0635   1.0313  
 items_recode (Intercept) 0.1141   0.3377  
 Residual                 1.5537   1.2465  
Number of obs: 1040, groups:  ID, 130; items_recode, 8

Fixed effects:
                                        Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                              3.01350    0.23121  22.21688  13.034 6.94e-12 ***
threatlevel1                            -0.22480    0.23895 263.69178  -0.941   0.3477    
extremity1                               2.11180    0.28221  12.57909   7.483 5.61e-06 ***
superhumanity1                           0.01503    0.15155 924.30143   0.099   0.9210    
threatlevel1:extremity1                  0.16775    0.22866 927.72532   0.734   0.4634    
threatlevel1:superhumanity1              0.15327    0.22966 929.31973   0.667   0.5047    
extremity1:superhumanity1               -0.43173    0.21860 938.21094  -1.975   0.0486 *  
threatlevel1:extremity1:superhumanity1  -0.10793    0.33440 948.21803  -0.323   0.7470    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) thrtl1 extrm1 sprhm1 thrtlvl1:x1 thrtlvl1:s1 ext1:1
threatlevl1 -0.452                                                    
extremity1  -0.600  0.158                                             
superhmnty1 -0.308  0.298  0.266                                      
thrtlvl1:x1  0.202 -0.453 -0.350 -0.329                               
thrtlvl1:s1  0.203 -0.453 -0.176 -0.661  0.509                        
extrmty1:s1  0.224 -0.217 -0.387 -0.727  0.477       0.481            
thrtlv1:1:1 -0.146  0.332  0.253  0.476 -0.731      -0.732      -0.653

I have trouble understanding the correlation of fixed effects, which are sometimes quite high. My searching of Google also has not helped me until now. Can somebody explain what these correlations mean?

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57240/how-do-i-interpret-the-correlations-of-fixed-effects-in-my-glmer-output It is not about the correlations of variables in your data, but rather the expected correlation of the coefficients if the model you estimated is the true data generating model and you ran the same experiment/study over and over. See also here for a nice simulation demonstration - https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/correlation-of-fixed-effects-in-lme4
